# How to tell django to use variable as html?

Tags: python, django

So, I have created an html page and it gets content from Python.I am able to get the text from the python program in view.py but unable to set it as an html tags. I have setup the css and js in HTML file but only this problem is arising. Is there a way out?
[image]

[image]

[image]

**IN SHORT**: How to tell Django that it is html and it has to simply join it in the code.(Not to use as text.)
*Details*
Python 3.8.2
Django 2.2.7
Edit: Haven't read the official documentation then.

Comment: probbaly, by using `<pre>...</pre>` tag

Comment: Though that didn't help in solving the above problem. But that was useful.I got to know.Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the HTML stored in your variable and want that HTML shown in your template?  You want the "safe" filter.

```
{{products|safe}}
```

Answer (score 1):

use safe filter with you field that contains html
read this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe